# Blender addon for creating crowd

Tags: particles

Just simple question : what is the proper addon for creating for example hundreds of bug crawling on wall. Where the bugs can make a contact with the surface like walking or crawling on a bumpy surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two add-ons in my mind that I could recommend for making crowd scenes easier to make, but you might know that it can also be achieved using particles.

Crowd Master: http://crowdmaster.org/

MCPrep: https://twitter.com/TheDuckCow/status/1070655223545425920